# how to click a button in listbox that IsHitTestVisible is false?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, listbox

In the listbox, I have a header item which `IsHitTestVisible` is false. This item contains a button that should be clickable. But it does not work now because of `IsHitTestVisible`.
How to enable only the button?

Please check an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP5cg.png)

Comment: Please add your xaml code to clarify.

Comment: It seems IsHitTestVisible="False" is not overridable in child-elements :(
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks - "if an element is a child element of an element that is not hit test visible, the effective value of the property on the child will remain false, even if attempting to set that value locally"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Before using this xaml code check your listbox header textblck is not coming over the button.maybe your textblock is coming over the button thats why button is not working.by setting width to  textblock you can solve this problem.else below code works for me**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">       
<Grid>
<ListBox Height="300" Width="300" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">       
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                        <Grid Background="White">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Listbox header" FontSize="17" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <Button Content="ok"  Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100">
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Button">                                                
                                                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="b1SetColor"/>                                              
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                            <Border Grid.Row="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <ScrollViewer  x:Name="ScrollViewer" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
    <ListBoxItem>ListBoxItem1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>ListBoxItem2</ListBoxItem>

</ListBox>
</Grid>
```

```
    void b1SetColor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = e.Source as Button;
        b.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
```

**Output** :after clciking on button it turns into red color

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is answering the question. Your code works trivially because your ListBox does not use IsHitTestVisible="False". Your ListBox is clickable; based on the question it must not be.

Comment: @bgh The person who was expecting the answer is already accepted the answer as it is fulling the requirement of his/her questions .so there is no point of downvote